# Under the DP hypothesis, does anything ever go in the Spec of NP?

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, determiners

I attach Carnie's illustration of "several people who she kissed" below:
[image]

My question is on the NP to N' branch (red boxed). I was taught that restrictive relatives clauses are adjuncts to NPs (which I don't really know why). So structurally speaking the RRC needs to be sister and daughter of a bar level constituent. And that's probably why NP goes to an extra layer N'. But what kind of construction can ever go in the specifier of NP, sister to the highest N' under the DP hypothesis? or go in the COMP of the top bar level constituent? In other words, can NP have any actual element in it that the topmost N' doesn't?

Picture from Carnie's textbook (3 ed.), Ch.12, p.371

Comment: Not a full answer, but I believe measure phrases go in SpecD under this hypothesis.

Comment: Couldn't you use that for compounds, i.e. *fire* in *fire brigade* or *truck* in *truck driver*? Not sure...